# How to find clients when you are a freelancer?

Tags: freelance-websites, web-development

How do I find clients? I've created my own website where I offer my services, I've posted links to that website on Facebook sale groups and still no one is calling. I don't have a big and impressive portfolio because I'm just starting, but I have the skills to do websites, shops and some web apps.

So, any tips for me? I really need to start earning money.

Comment: Ask your friends to disseminate a message for you, telling in a pleasant but honest way what services you want to provide. Ask only to people you know well, and tell them to specifically send to contacts likely to be interested.

Comment: You can register with freelance websites such as Upwork or Fiver. Then, in your profile on the sites, have a link to a portfolio page.

Answer (score 3):

1. Build a "demo" project. Something that could likely be an actual project. This way you can make your portfolio bigger.
2. Organize courses about the technologies you know. Is another way to find potential interested customer. I found two of the main customers in my life this way.

Comment: thanks a lot, this first thing is actually amazing, but I don't really understand this second thing, could u explain?

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, you could create a website for a particular field, say a jewellery store, then contact stores with poor websites showing them what their website could look like. If they say no, move on to the next jewellery store with a poor website. Once someone sees the end product, they are far more likely to purchase the site off of you.